# Internet not working after enabling Power on by PCI-E

Tags: linux, networking, wake-on-lan, networkmanager

I tried to setup wake on lan for my Ubuntu 19.04 PC. According to the docs I should enable "Power on PCI-E" option in a BIOS. Which i did. Set up ethetool and so on. After some time I started feeling that something is wrong with my internet connection. The first noticed problem was that my internet does not work immediately after power on. So what I saw is I had no connection for 3 minutes and then got back. I was thinking that's ok, maybe its tradeoff of the WOL. But the next day I completelly had no internet connection. I rebooted many times, I tried to play with the settings (reset them all) and the only thing that helped me was turned off "Power on PCI-E" option in BIOS.

My question is how can I setup WOL and do not have problems with my internet connection?

Additional info I set up my wol to the network interface (sorry if the terminology isn't right) named ent0s5 which is responsible for internet connection too as I see.

Update: I'm still having issue with my internet connection. It boots up randomly after restart of PC

Update 2: When i try to go for any website I see "err_proxy_connection_failure" error

Update 3: NAT forwarding from my router.
[image]